# hibernate, query on embeddable object

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, embeddable

Is it possible to query on Embeddable object from separate query?

E.g., we have

```
@Entity
class Person{
...
@Embedded
private Address address;
...
}


@Embeddable
class Address{
private String street;
...

}
```

is it possible to create hql-query like this :

`getHibernateTemplate.find("from Address");`  ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Question does not appear to be about programming an embedded system.  Retagged

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible since embedded object does not have table associated with it without a context of outer object. For example, you can have `Address` embedded in different entities mapped on different tables. How would you figure which table to use?

It may be possible, however, to do something like

```
select p.address from Person p
```

Comment: Indeed this is possible to create a query from the main class : "select a from Person p join p.address a where p.name=:name"